# Permisos para ejecutar un archivo desde PHP

Tags: php

estoy tratando de ejecutar un programa desde PHP
Pero no obtengo el mismo resultado que al hacerlo manual.
Hasta ahora, he usado estO:

```
$answer = shell_exec("ruta_completa_al_exe");
echo $answer . "</br>";
```

Pero por alguna razón, el programa no logra completar su trabajo de este modo, ya que debe realizar un envío de datos, y con este método, no lo hace.
En páginas de Stack Overflow, me topé con [esto:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983453/12429790)
Un código que crea una tarea programada y ejecuta esa tarea.

```
function ex($command)
{
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /F /Create /TN _law /TR "' . $command . '"" /SC DAILY /RU 
INTERACTIVE');
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "_law');
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "_law" /F');
}
ex("C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe");
```

Lamentablemente, esta forma no funciona actualmente en mi caso.
Esto por que, a pesar de intentar el envío, no hay respuesta de este.
El programa debería retornar valores, pero solo retorna en 0.

---

UPDATE: He intentado ejecutar el .exe desde un .bat, y al parecer le faltan permisos de todos modos. No se si de administrador o algo mas.

```
start ruta_al_exe
```

Comment: En la función no estás recogiendo ni retornando ni mostrando nada en ninguna de las llamadas a `shee_exec`, por lo que es lógico que no veas nada. Eso suponiendo que tus comandos están bien y que producen alguna salida. Prueba entonces a mostrar las salidas de algún modo. Si aún así no muestra nada, [según esta nota del Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php#106250), a veces hay que añadir  **`2>&1`** al final del parámetro.

Comment: No es eso, no hay que mostrar nada la verdad. Lo que hay que hacer, es que el programa se ejecute con todos los permisos, como si fuese el usuario el que lo hace.

Comment: Revisa los logs. Si es un asunto de permisos entonces el usuario de PHP debe tener permiso para ejecutar esos comandos / modificar esas carpetas, etc. Pero ten cuidado con otorgar permisos a la ligera. Yo este tipo de cosas las haría en un archivo a nivel de la consola y programaría un cron o una tarea para que se ejecute con la periodicidad requerida. Sería más simple, más rápido y más seguro. No hace falta pasar por PHP para esto.

Comment: El tema es que tiene que hacerlo leyendo datos del servidor mysql. En cuanto a permisos, como los modifico y otorgo entonces ??

Comment: Eso depende del sistema operativo (por las rutas parece que es Windows). Pues ejecutando el comando que exista en Windows para otorgar el tipo de permisos necesitado para ese usuario. Pero debes verificar primero si es ese el problema o no, leyendo los logs de error antes de ponerte a dar permisos a la ligera. En cuanto a lo que dices sobre MySQL, desde la consola puedes conectar / ejecutar consultas SQL. La consola es un nivel más bajo de programación (bajo en cuanto más cercano a la fuente) y por tanto más rápido y más seguro para este tipo de cosas.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar otro tipo de atajo para poder ejecutarlo, con el uso de un acceso directo. En los logs no hay errores sobre esto, por lo que error no hay.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $param="gente.txt";
    $ejec="elimina.exe ".$param1;
    $command = escapeshellcmd($ejec);
    $output = shell_exec($command);
```

De esa manera me ha resultado sin problemas y sin agregar ningún permiso sobre el archivo ejecutable

Comment: No resulta, el programa llamado debe enviar y recibir datos, de este modo no retorna nada. Si se ejecuta manual, todo ok. Creo que hacen falta permisos.